# Docker in Docker unable to push

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm trying to execute docker commands inside of a Docker container (don't ask why). To do so I start up a container by running.

```
sudo docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it my_docker_image
```

I am able to run all of the docker commands (pull, login, images, etc) but when I try to push to my remote (Gitlab) registry I get denied access. Yes, I did do a docker login and was able to successfully log in.

When looking at the Gitlab logs I see an error telling me no access token was sent with the push. After I do a docker login I see a /root/.docker/config.json with the remote url and a string of random characters (my credentials in base 64 I believe)? I'm using an access token as my password because i have MFA enabled on my Gitlab server.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: as it states [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html), you have to use a special `gitlab-ci-token` in order to push registry connected to your project.

Comment: @scipsycho Thank you for pointing me to that page, very helpful. I was using a personal access token with the API scope which should have write access to the registry right? I used the gitlab-ci-token you recommended and am still getting the "denied: access forbidden"  error. Only thing that i did differently from the tutorial was use the centos6 image and not docker:stable. Would that cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the issue by using docker:stable as my runner image. Not quite sure what the problem was with the centos:centos7 image.